# Samba 4 has high CPU usage when accessing mapped drive through Windows

Tags: linux, centos, windows, samba

I have noticed that when I access my Samba share from Windows, the `smbd` daemon will always use aprox 10-20% CPU - no matter if the share is used or not from Windows. Even if I close the share/window, `smbd` will continue using CPU and only a reboot/shutdown of my Windows can get the CPU usage down to normal.

This is when I have just rebooted/started my Windows - the share is mapped but not accessed yet. It will have this "red" status in Windows until I access it:

[image: Share as seen from Windows after a reboot]

Before I do anything else I check the `smbstatus` and `top` on my Linux:

[image: smbstatus after a reboot]

There is no problem so far - the CPU usage is not noticable at all in `top` so everything is still good.

BUT ... when I then access the share from Windows, the Linux CPU immediately raises to 10-20%:

[image: High CPU when drive is accessed]

And the `smbstatus` always shows some locked(?) files which for sure(?) is not accessed from my Windows:

[image: Files accessed when mapped drive is accessed]

The `testparm` shows my `smb.conf` configuration:

[image: Samba configuration file]

The only way I can "fix this" is by either rebooting my Windows or unmap the drive/share.

One more strange thing - when I have unmapped the share/drive, I can of course still access the share via UNC... and when accessing it through UNC it does NOT raise the CPU at all!? Weird!

My hardware is quite recent/uptodate:

Server:
Core i5 1.5-2.9GHz dual core/HT
16GB RAM
Samsung 850 Pro (512GB)

Client:
Windows 8.1

I have used the same configuration on a CentOS 6 installation without any problems. I have also tried disabling whatever I think can communicate with the network share on my Windows computer (antivirus and backup software).

Can anyone help nailing this problem down?

Comment: I observe the same behavior on one of my samba servers, did you ever find an explanation for that and is it really abnormal?

Comment: If `samba` isn't the dance you want to dance use `NFS`. Linux/*nix native network fs and maybe a bit less resource hogging.

http://superuser.com/questions/525473/how-do-i-mount-an-nfs-share-in-windows-8

Comment: I've the same problem with macOS clients here.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly a bit late but I found this, while having a similar problem.

I have a Raspberry Pi B+ with samba configured as a drive store, with a direct connection to my laptop over Ethernet.

My setup is as follows:

- several external hard drives connected to raspberry pi.
- Raspberry pi uses direct Ethernet connection to my laptop.

I have found:

- high cpu usage by smbd when reading from external (45%)
- high cpu usage by mount.ntfs when writing to external (46%)

Considering specs of B+, it seems somewhat believable since a simple apt update takes a minute of so if just refreshing list...

[This](http://www.enterprisenetworkingplanet.com/windows/article.php/3849061/Use-Samba-With-Windows-7-Clients.htm) might make for some good reading